# Backup Azure SQL Database using Azure Devops

Tags: azure, azure-devops, azure-sql-database

We are using Azure devops to deploy changes to Azure SQL database using dacpac. I want to add a step in the build or release pipeline to take backup of the database but didn't find any task in devops marketplace. Can anyone suggest some way to take db backup in devops pipeline. It will be very helpful. Thanks.

Comment: Hi friend, any update for this issue?

Answer (score 4):

Azure CLI with [az sql db](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/azure/sql/db?view=azure-cli-latest) commands can be used to manage your Azure Database.
Azure Devops Service provides [Azure CLI task](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/deploy/azure-cli?view=azure-devops) to call Azure CLI in Azure Devops pipelins.

And here're two documents that you can refer to:

[Use CLI to backup an Azure SQL single database to an Azure storage container](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/sql-database/scripts/sql-database-backup-database-cli)

[Use CLI to restore a single database in Azure SQL Database to an earlier point in time](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/sql-database/scripts/sql-database-restore-database-cli)